# Google Sheets as JSON: Need Partial Match in Cell

Tags: json, google-apps-script, get, google-sheets-api

Using [THIS](https://gist.github.com/ronaldsmartin/47f5239ab1834c47088e) script by @ronaldsmartin to filter Google Spreadsheet as a JSON feed but need **partial** key match in sheet cell values... i.e: key is "apple" and via partial match the result would be "apple sauce"

Thank you in advance....

Current script includes:

```
{

// Filter for matching terms.
data = data.filter(function(entry) {

var matches = true;

for (var k in keys) {

  var key = keys[k].replace(/\s+/g, '_');

  var searchTerm = request.parameters[key];

  // Use the string form of the value since params are strings by default

  if (searchTerm != undefined)

    matches = matches && ("" + entry[key] == searchTerm);

}

// Matches is true iff all params are undefined or all values for keys match.

return matches;
});
```

If helpful, please find the full script below:

{

```
/**

 * Main method is called when the script receives a GET request.

 * Receives the request, generates and returns the output.

 */

    function doGet(request) {

  // Get request params.

      var sheetKey  = request.parameters.id;

      var sheetName = request.parameters.sheet;

      var callback  = request.parameters.callback;

      var headerRow = request.parameters.header;

      var startRow  = request.parameters.startRow;
```

// Parse the spreadsheet.

```
      var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetKey);

      var keys = getHeaderRowKeys_(spreadsheet, sheetName, headerRow);

      var data = readData_(spreadsheet, sheetName, keys, startRow);
```

// Filter for matching terms.

```
      data = data.filter(function(entry) {

        var matches = true;

        for (var k in keys) {

          var key = keys[k].replace(/\s+/g, '_');

          var searchTerm = request.parameters[key];

  // Use the string form of the value since params are strings by default

          if (searchTerm != undefined)

            matches = matches && ("" + entry[key] == searchTerm);

        }

  // Matches is true iff all params are undefined or all values for keys match.

        return matches;

      });
```

// Write and return the response.

```
      var response = JSON.stringify({ records: data });

      var output = ContentService.createTextOutput();

      if (callback == undefined) {
```

// Serve as JSON

```
        output.setContent(response).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
      } else {
```

// Serve as JSONP

```
        output.setContent(callback + "(" + response + ")")

            .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);

     }

      return output;

    }

    /**

     * Get a row in a spreadsheet as an Object, using the values in the header row as

     * keys and the corresponding row values as the values.

     * @param spreadsheet Spreadsheet object housing the sheet and header

     * @param sheetName Name of the specific sheet in the spreadsheet with the data

     * @param properties Optional array of keys to use for the row values. Default is the first row.

     * @param startRowNum Optional top row number of the rows to parse. The default is the second row (i.e., below the header).

     */

    function readData_(spreadsheet, sheetName, properties, startRowNum) {

      if (typeof properties == "undefined") {

        properties = getHeaderRowKeys_(spreadsheet, sheetName);

      }

      var rows = getDataRows_(spreadsheet, sheetName, startRowNum);

      var data = [];

      for (var r = 0, l = rows.length; r < l; r++) {

        var row = rows[r];

        var record = {};

        for (var p in properties) {

          record[properties[p]] = row[p];

        }

        data.push(record);

      }

      return data;

    }

    /**

     * Parse spreadsheet data as an array of Javascript Objects.

     * @param spreadsheet Spreadsheet object with the data to get

     * @param sheetName Name of the specific sheet in the spreadsheet with the data

     * @param startRowNum Optional top row number of the rows to parse. The default is

     * the second row (i.e., below the header).

     */

    function getDataRows_(spreadsheet, sheetName, startRowNum) {

      if (typeof startRowNum == "undefined") startRowNum = 2;

      var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);

      return sheet.getRange(startRowNum, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 3,

     sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();

    }

    /**

     * Return the array of keys used in the header, replacing whitespace with underscores.

     * @param spreadsheet Spreadsheet object housing the sheet and header

     * @param sheetName Name of the specific sheet in the spreadsheet whose header values to get

     * @param rowNum Optional exact row number of the header. Default is the first row.

     */

    function getHeaderRowKeys_(spreadsheet, sheetName, rowNum) {

      if (typeof rowNum == "undefined") rowNum = 1;

      return getHeaderRow_(spreadsheet, sheetName, rowNum).map(function(value)                   { 

        return value.replace(/\s+/g, '_');

      });

    }

    /**

     * Get the values in the header row of the given sheet in a spreadsheet

     * @param spreadsheet Spreadsheet object housing the sheet and header

     * @param sheetName Name of the specific sheet in the spreadsheet whose header values to get

     * @param rowNum Exact row number of the header.

     */

    function getHeaderRow_(spreadsheet, sheetName, rowNum) {

      var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);

      return sheet.getRange(rowNum, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];

    }


    /********************************** TESTS **********************************/


    /**
     * Basic test logs a request and response. Use View -> Logs to check if it's
     * correct.
     * (In the future maybe actually check equality to expected output.)
     * @param request The HTTP request to test
     */
    function runTest_(request) {
      Logger.log(request);
      Logger.log(doGet(request).getContent().toString());
    }

    /**
     * Test the original functionality of returning all objects
     * in the spreadsheet in JSON.
     */
    function test1() {
      runTest_({
          parameters : {
            id : "0AgviZ9NWh5fvdDdNMlI2aXRCR2lCX1B1alZ6ZjZxSkE",
            sheet : "Summary",
            header : 2,
            startRow : 3,
          }
      });
    }

    /**
     * Test filtering on the spreadsheet JSON for one value.
     */
    function test2() {
      runTest_({
          parameters : {
            id : "0AgviZ9NWh5fvdDdNMlI2aXRCR2lCX1B1alZ6ZjZxSkE",
            sheet : "Summary",
            header : 2,
            Status : "Associate"
          }
      });
    }

    /**
     * Test stricter filtering on the spreadsheet for multiple values.
     */
    function test3() {
      runTest_({
          parameters : {
            id : "0AgviZ9NWh5fvdDdNMlI2aXRCR2lCX1B1alZ6ZjZxSkE",
            sheet : "Summary",
            header : 2,
            startRow : 3,
            First_Name : "Greatest",
            Last_Name : "Ever"
          }
      });
    }
    }
```